# why does my app crash when cursor tries to fetch data from db?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fetch a simple image and text from db and displaying them in a listview, but it crashes when the debugger reaches that point, i want to know why this could happen?

*Raiding table:*

```
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public class Schema {
    public Schema() {

    }

    public static abstract class Raiding implements BaseColumns {



        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "raiding";
        public static final String _ID = "_ID";
        public static final String ATTACK_NAME = "attack_name";
        public static final String ATTACK_TH = "attack_th";
        public static final String ATTACK_Type = "attack_type";
        public static final String ATTACK_ElixirUsage = "elixir_usage";
        public static final String ATTACK_Image =  "attack_image";
    }

}
```

*dbHelper:* includes two methods:
1: adding a new row to db
2: reading rows from db: the problem is here, I guess, I used debugger, when it was going to invoke this method, It suddenly crashes

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import sqlitemodel.Schema.Raiding;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "strategies.db";
    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
    public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + Raiding.TABLE_NAME + "("
            + Raiding._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Raiding.ATTACK_NAME
            + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + Raiding.ATTACK_TH + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
            + Raiding.ATTACK_Type + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
            + Raiding.ATTACK_ElixirUsage + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
            + Raiding.ATTACK_Image + " Blob" + ")";

    public MyDataBaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.d("db", "created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("table!", "Created!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Raiding.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(arg0);
    }

    public void addRaiding(RaidingClass raidingClass) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Raiding.ATTACK_NAME, raidingClass.name);
        values.put(Raiding.ATTACK_TH, raidingClass.th);
        values.put(Raiding.ATTACK_Type, raidingClass.type);
        values.put(Raiding.ATTACK_ElixirUsage, raidingClass.usage);
        values.put(Raiding.ATTACK_Image, raidingClass.image);

        db.insert(Raiding.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public List<RaidingClass> getAllRaidingAttacks() {

        List<RaidingClass> raidingAttackList = new ArrayList<RaidingClass>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Raiding.TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        Log.d("count", String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                RaidingClass raidingClass = new RaidingClass();
                raidingClass.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                raidingClass.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                raidingClass.setTh(cursor.getString(2));
                raidingClass.setType(cursor.getString(3));
                raidingClass.setUsage(cursor.getString(4));
                raidingClass.setImage(cursor.getBlob(5));
                raidingAttackList.add(raidingClass);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        db.close();
        return raidingAttackList;

    }

}
```

*RaidingClass*

```
public class RaidingClass {

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String th;
    public String type;
    public String usage;
    public byte[] image;

    public RaidingClass() {

    }

    public RaidingClass(int id, String name, String th, String type, String usage,
            byte[] image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.th = th;
        this.type = type;
        this.usage = usage;
        this.image = image;

    }

    public RaidingClass(String name, String th, String type, String usage,
            byte[] image) {

        this.name = name;
        this.th = th;
        this.type = type;
        this.usage = usage;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void setID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setTh(String th) {
        this.th = th;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setUsage(String usage) {
        this.usage = usage;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

}
```

*mainActivity.java:*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnattack;
    MyDataBaseHelper dbHelper;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbHelper = new MyDataBaseHelper(this);
        dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.barcher);
        //
        // // convert bitmap to byte
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
        dbHelper.addRaiding(new RaidingClass("barcher", "8", "R", "many",
                imageInByte));

        btnattack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnattack);
        btnattack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        RaidingAttack.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

*RaidingAttack:* this is the class which I try to invoke the getAllRaidingAttacks() method to fetch the corresponding row values.

```
public class RaidingAttack extends Activity {
    ArrayList<RaidingClass> raidingDetails = new ArrayList<RaidingClass>();
    RaidingAdapter raidingAdapter;

    MyDataBaseHelper dbHelper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_raiding);

        dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        List<RaidingClass> raiding = dbHelper.getAllRaidingAttacks();

        for (RaidingClass rd : raiding) {
            raidingDetails.add(rd);
        }

        raidingAdapter = new RaidingAdapter(this,
                R.layout.activity_list_singlerow, raidingDetails);
        ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        dataList.setAdapter(raidingAdapter);
    }

}
```

this is exactly where the debugger stops and the app crashes:

```
List<RaidingClass> raiding = dbHelper.getAllRaidingAttacks();
```

and i checked the db, the image and texts are inserted, but I don't know why the cursor is null!

*and this is the error log:*

```
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.masoudseraj.clashofclansstrategies/com.masoudseraj.clashofclansstrategies.RaidingAttack}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at com.masoudseraj.clashofclansstrategies.RaidingAttack.onCreate(RaidingAttack.java:24)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
10-20 05:11:29.102: E/AndroidRuntime(14511):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: and what are crash logs ?

Comment: it is added right now

Comment: Did you find out where the null exception is occurring on the line? what have you figured out. How far have you gone into debugging the dbhelper's class? Code dumping like this and expecting us to tell you...

Comment: @t0mm13b well I copied the line

Comment: any other info should I give about the code?

Comment: whats at com.masoudseraj.clashofclansstrategies.RaidingAttack.onCreate(RaidingAttack.java:24) ?

Comment: where is the output of the log showing the messages coming from dbhelper?

Comment: @MemLeak this is written on line 24: dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: You did not instantiate dbHelper?

Comment: @t0mm13b should I instanciate it  again? 
i did it once when I was trying to create db on the mainActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbHelper is not initialised in `RaidingAttack`

```
public class RaidingAttack extends Activity {
    ArrayList<RaidingClass> raidingDetails = new ArrayList<RaidingClass>();
    RaidingAdapter raidingAdapter;

    MyDataBaseHelper dbHelper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_raiding);
        //init dbHelper
        dbHelper = new MyDataBaseHelper(this);
        dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```